# Visual Studio Code Intellisense for JSON files imported via require

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there a way to have intellisense in VSC work with json files imported via the require method in nodeJS?

```
var jsonObj = require('path/to/jsonFile.json')
```

I'd like for it to predict the properties of the json object imported from the file as I code.

Comment: No, in order for that to be supported you would need a schema for the .json file and the very nature of .json is there is no schema.

Comment: You could create and map a schema though if you have one you use consistently:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in all instances, but when I'm creating JSON for configurations or other static data that could have been stored in a JSON file, I store it in a .js file and use the module.exports to expose it. This way the Intellisense picks it up and you get the auto-complete in VSC.

```
module.exports = {"data":{"foo":"bar"}}
```